InfluxDB v1 or v2 for a new project?
I'm starting a new project and I want to use InfluxDB. I've never used it before, any release. The new project aims at a long term lifecycle.
The InfluxDB official website states v1 could be easier to migrate to the upcoming v3 ("If you plan on upgrading to InfluxDB v3, we recommend starting with InfluxDB v1 to ease the migration process"), while v2 might be harder, but I feel that choosing an older version of the database for a new project at least requires solid motivation (more solid than "might be harder to upgrade").
So what are the expected obstacles in the upgrade path from v2 to v3 that are easier to manage when upgrading from v1 to v3?
Should I really consider InfluxDB v1 for a new long term project?
